# Will Redis Pub/Sub keep or persist past data when client is unsubscribed from topic?

Tags: python, redis, message, persist, unsubscribe

I have a Django project with Tornado websocket opened and is subscribed to a topic in my Redis Pub/Sub. I am using asyncio and aioredis. Before page refresh, browser close or navigation out of that page, I will call for the websocket to close, which will unsubscribe from that topic.

The issue here is sometimes when I change pages or refresh the page, a bunch of messages from the past will be pumped back into the newly opened websocket. It doesn't happen every time, and I'm not sure what else I can do to make sure the past messages don't come back on page refresh. I've already made sure the websocket will close and unsubscribe from the topic on page refresh/window unload.

Does Redis Pub/Sub keep old messages somewhere while the client is unsubscribed? And when the client subscribes back to the same topic, the old messages are sent out? Is this normal behaviour for Redis Pub/Sub? I'm under the impression that Redis Pub/Sub doesn't persist messages and if client is unsubscribed, the messages just get dropped for that client.

I need to make sure when page reloads, the old messages don't get pumped back to the websocket.

This is how I wrote the RedisChannel to execute the pub/sub functions:

```
import aioredis
class RedisChannel(object):
    '''
    Redis backed pub-sub websocket channel.
    '''
    async def subscribe(self, **kwargs):
        '''
        Subscribe to topics
        '''
        topics = kwargs.get('topics')
        return await self.conn.subscribe(*topics)

    async def unsubscribe(self, **kwargs):
        '''
        Unsubscribe to topics
        '''
        topics = kwargs.get('topics')
        return await self.conn.unsubscribe(*topics)

    async def send(self, **kwargs):
        data = {}

        # If client socket is provided, only send to this socket.
        ws = kwargs.get('ws')

        # Topic for this message. Compulsory for broadcast.
        topic = kwargs.get('topic')

        # Usually JSON
        if kwargs.get('data'):
            data['data'] = kwargs.get('data')

        # I'm using 60 seconds right now just to try to limit the list of past messages
        # But the behaviour I need is 0 past messages on page reload in browser
        push_event = True
        if kwargs.get('timestamp'):
            event_timestamp = kwargs.get("timestamp", 0)
            data['timestamp'] = event_timestamp
            # logger.debug(data)
            current_time = timezone.now()
            if event_timestamp:
                event_dt = get_utc_time(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(event_timestamp))
                if event_dt:
                    time_apart = current_time - event_dt
                    duration = abs(time_apart.total_seconds())
                    logger.debug("Time apart between event and current time = {}".format(duration))
                    if duration >= 60:
                        push_event = False

        if not push_event:
            data = {}

        return await self.conn.publish_json(topic, json.dumps(data, separators=(',', ': ')))

    async def connect(self):
        redis_settings = settings['redis']['channel']

        self.conn = await aioredis.create_redis_pool(
                (
                    redis_settings.get('host'),
                    redis_settings.get('port')
                ),
                db=redis_settings.get('db'),
                minsize=2,
                maxsize=redis_settings.get('max_connections'),
                encoding='utf-8'
            )
```

This is how I wrote the websocket handler to subscribe/unsubscribe to a Redis topic:

```
import asyncio, json

ws_channel = RedisChannel()
asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(ws_channel.connect())

async def reader(ch, ws):
    while (await ch.wait_message()):
        data = await ch.get_json()

        if data:
            ws.write_message(data)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.001)
        # time.sleep

class ResultsWsHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        try:
            self.write_message(json.dumps('Websocket opened.'))
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(str(e))

    def on_message(self, message):
        asyncio.ensure_future(self.on_message_async(message))

    async def on_message_async(self, message):
    # async def on_message(self, message):
        data = json.loads(message)

        action = data.get('action', None)

        topics = data.get('cameras', [])

        if topics or action is not None:
            try:
                action = int(action)

                if action == 0:  # 0 - heartbeat
                    logger.debug('Heartbeat.')

                    param = {'type': 0}
                    self.write_message(json.dumps(param))

                elif action == 1:  # 1 - subscribe
                    channels = await ws_channel.subscribe(topics=topics)

                    logger.debug(f'Successfully subscribed from {topics}.')
                    self.write_message(json.dumps(f'Successfully subscribed to {topics}.'))

                    task_list = []
                    for c in channels:
                        task_list.append(asyncio.ensure_future(reader(c, self)))

                    await asyncio.wait(task_list)

                elif action == 2:  # 2 - unsubscribe
                    await ws_channel.unsubscribe(topics=topics)

                    logger.debug(f'Successfully unsubscribe from {topics}.')
                    self.write_message(json.dumps(f'Successfully unsubscribe from {topics}.'))

                else:
                    logger.debug(f'Other: {data}')

            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(json.dumps(str(e), separators=(',', ': ')))
                self.write_message(json.dumps(str(e), separators=(',', ': ')))
```

Comment: Redis pubsub makes [no guarantees](https://www.redisgreen.net/blog/pubsub-intro/) for message delivery. It's more like fire and forget. A published message to a channel will only be delivered to subscribers which are subscribed to that channel at the time. There must be something else going awry in your workflow.

Comment: You're right. I've overlooked a part of the code and the websocket didn't get closed when the user exits the page. That's why when I re-entered the page, I get 2 subscribers, and that number adds up. Thanks for helping out! :D